# PeerJS not working with turn servers

Tags: webrtc, stun, turn, peerjs

I am Working with peerJS,

In LAN all is OK, but if I use turn servers from cellphone connection the stream connection fails.

The mediaStream is passed in peerJS connection.on('stream', (stream)=>{..
but crashes just after this, the problem seems related to stun/turn negotiation, here the console logs:

```
.callConnection.on('stream')... <-- I receive the stream

...

PeerJS:  Set remoteDescription: ANSWER for: PEER_ID
PeerJS:  Added ICE candidate for: PEER_ID 
PeerJS:  iceConnectionState is disconnected, closing connections to PEER_ID 
    myHandler.Negotiation of connection to PEER_ID failed.
```

And then this error catched:

```
Error: Negotiation of connection to PEER_ID failed.
    at RTCPeerConnection.pc.oniceconnectionstatechange [as onicechange]
```

and here fails

what could it be?

I am not sure if it matters, in the signaling negotiation LOGS I cannot see the configured TURN IP, I only see other IPs:

```
{"type":"CANDIDATE","src":"itEthicsoftIdeskUserUUU1","dst":"itEthicsoftIdeskDeviceDDDfa53da20-5cc8-83dc-e259-df0ef328fbb7","payload":{"candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:1028452565 1 udp 2113937151 10.98.5.173 42892 typ host generation 0 ufrag lewL network-cost 50","sdpMid":"audio","sdpMLineIndex":0},"type":"media","connectionId":"mc_yzox790yv9b"}}
{"type":"CANDIDATE","src":"itEthicsoftIdeskUserUUU1","dst":"itEthicsoftIdeskDeviceDDDfa53da20-5cc8-83dc-e259-df0ef328fbb7","payload":{"candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:842163049 1 udp 1677729535 37.162.11.125 44523 typ srflx raddr 10.98.5.173 rport 42892 generation 0 ufrag lewL network-cost 50","sdpMid":"audio","sdpMLineIndex":0},"type":"media","connectionId":"mc_yzox790yv9b"}}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: actually, I migrated to simple-peer, not a really solution but a better stable alternative. But it requires separate signaling server, that was included in PeerJS

Comment: I've been able to get it working on LTE using TURN servers when I changed the config; while the config for WebRTC is usually `urls:`, Peer evaluates this but actually doesn't seem to use the turn server unless you use the key `url:` in the config. Took 12 hours but finally managed to get it to work! (at least on android)

Comment: Check about:webrtc in firefox and chrome://webrtc-internals in chrome to see whether iceServers is an empty array or not.